# jQuery Mobile swipe navigation exception

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, swipe

I have a series of pages inside one document, I navigate from page to page making use of swipe in touch devices.

What I dont know how to do, is to stop the swipe event once I reach certain page id.

This is the code I am using form my navigation:

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
if (nextpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
}
});
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
if (prevpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
reverse: true}, true, true);
}
});
```

I am using JQM 1.3

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is your question? Your code already prevents you to swipe if you  are showing first and the last page, what do you want more?

Comment: Sorry I didnt make myself clear, What happen is that I have some hidden pages that are called using click events. They should not be seen in regular swipe navigation, They were put intenionally at the bottom of the document, so I need a way to prevent this pages from being accessed this way.

Comment: I think I understand you want to turn of swiperight or swipeleft when you reach certain page, am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/GXex5/

```
$(document).off('swipeleft').on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){    
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'article2') {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
    }
    event.handled = true;

});

$(document).off('swiperight').on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){   
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
    }
    event.handled = true;
});
```

Basically all you need is this code:

```
if($(this).attr('id') == 'article2') {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

This code will check if some page has a certain name and if it is so it will prevent default action (event). Also dont forget to pass a event object in your code, so

change this:

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
```

to this:

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(event){
```

Comment: Fantastic example. I am already using this code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Use the below to define next and previous page ID, if it equals to the page you don't want to show, do nothing.

```
var DoNothing = 'DoNothing';

// fetch ID of next page in DOM
var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]')[0].id;

// fetch ID of previous page in DOM
var prevpage = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')[0].id;

// logic
if(nextpage == DoNothing || prevpage == DoNothing) {
// Do nothing!
}
```